# How do I self-host Jekyll?

Tags: github, deployment, jekyll

I don't want to use github to host my new portfolio, I want to host it from my own site. How do I do this properly? Clearly, simply uploading all the files don't work (I just see Jekyll template text).

Has anyone done this?

Comment: You could install Apache and then just generate your jekyll site locally and just copy the contents of _site to apache's htdocs folder.

Comment: I wanted something automatic and seamless. I've ditched Jekyll for Wordpress though. It's clunky, but I can make it do what I want.

Comment: Yikes, I went back to Wordpress? LOL I don't remember that year, I must've went back to Jekyll immediately. Now I'm looking into creating a custom blogging platform...that's progress for ya!

Comment: Haha, yeah and don't put it behind Apache, use nginx lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to generate the site with Jekyll, and then upload the generated files to your web server. Jekyll's [Usage](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Usage) and [Deployment](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Deployment) docs explain in more detail.

Comment: Oh dear, I didn't think to look there. Thanks!

Comment: I just wish there was a super dumb idiots' guide to deployment. :/

Comment: @NetOperatorWibby not sure what you mean by "my own site", but you could deploy to Heroku. Doesn't get more idiot proof than that. Google around, but here is a [quick guide](http://chriscontinanza.com/2011/06/15/Jekyll-to-heroku.html).

Comment: @kale I'm trying to follow the tutorial, but I am unable to push to Heroku. Am I supposed to run the commands while in the "_site" folder?